# Convergence in distribution of $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\theta)}{\theta}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I read in a book that since $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\theta)}{\theta}$ converges in distribution to the standard normal distribution, i.e., $N(0,1)$ using the Central Limit Theorem, that $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\theta)$ converges in distribution to $N(0,\theta)$. Can someone please explain why this is true?

Note: it is also given that $E(X_i) = Var(X_i) = \theta$ and the question is about finding the limiting distribution of the mean of the Poisson distribution.

Comment: Except if you are using a very nonstandard notation for a normal distribution, it should converge to $N(0,\theta^2)$, that is, its variance would be $\theta^2$ and its standard deviation $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\theta)}{\theta}$ and put $W_n=\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\theta)$.
Then for $w\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
P(W_n\leq w)=P(\theta Y_n\leq w)=P(Y_{n}\leq w/\theta)\to P(Z\leq w/\theta)=P(\theta Z\leq w)
$$
since $Y_{n}$ converges in distribution to a standard normal where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. By the definition of convergence in distribution in terms of distribution functions it follows that
$$
W_{n}\stackrel{d}{\to}\theta Z\sim N(0, \theta)
$$
where $\theta$ is the standard deviation.

Comment: Doesn't your answer show that $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\theta)$ converges in distribution to $N(0, \frac{w}{\theta})$?